# express generator, local jquery not working

Tags: jquery, express, handlebars.js, express-generator

I am trying to learn express and the express generator and got stuck on something basic I suspect.  I can't serve jquery from a local directory.

The steps I followed

1. create a directory called help

   >mkdir help

   >cd help
2. create an express server in help directory and install it's dependencies with command

   help>express --view=hbs app

   help>cd app

   app>init install

   app> cd ..

3) create a default package.json in help directory with command

```
help>npm init
```

4) create a 2 line index.js file containing

```
const app = require("./app/app")

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

5) download jquery into the folder

```
help/app/public/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
```

6) added jquery to the help\app\views\layout.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <script> src="/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" </script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    {{{body}}}
  </body>
</html>
```

7) added an alert in help\app\views\index.hbs to see if jquery loaded correctly

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>Welcome to {{title}}</p>
<script>
    $(()=> alert("hi"))
</script>
```

8) this results in an error

```
(index):12 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

So jquery appears not loaded. I have been running in circles for the last hour. 
This express generator appears really cool and makes creating the skeleton of a server very fast, so would like to figure out what I did wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

silly error on my part.  The line

```
<script> src="/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" </script>
```

should have been

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
```